# Return a JSON array object in script in JSP

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

In a JSP file I have a script tag which try to import the request attributes which are in JSON format and make an object out of it with few selected fields.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    attribute_meta= [];

    var attributeData  = <%=request.getAttribute("attributes")%>;
    for ( i = 0; i < attributeData.size(); i++) {
        attribute_meta.push({colName: attributeData[i].colName, Type: attributeData[i].type, Value: attributeData[i].value});
    }
    </script>
```

I tried these also

```
var attributeData  = JSON.parse(<%=request.getAttribute("attributes")%>);

var attributeData  =  JSON.parse('${attributes}');
```

But it still didn't work. because the output is not JSON.

The request has a attribute called attributes which is like

```
        [
           abc{
               colname=somename,
               type=int,
               value=2,
               field=xyz,
               somemorefields=asda
           }
           pqr{
               colname= asd,
               type= int,
               value= 22,
               field= xyz,
               some more fields =asda
           }
        ]
```

Comment: You've shown us your JSP (but not enough to determine what the attributes attribute actually is) but you haven't shown us the JavaScript is generated or told us how this is different from the JavaScript you want to generate.

Comment: @Olayinka O — That's a very unhelpful edit. The live demo only works for JavaScript/HTML/CSS. You can't put JSP (which runs server-side!!) in it!

Comment: @Quentin I tidied the code... The question says `text/javascript`! I answered based purely on what's provided! which was the primary tag anyway.

Comment: @OlayinkaO — It's JavaScript generated by JSP and has embedded JSP inside it.

Comment: @Quentin I am working on a jsp in which i need to write a script to cache the attributes which is one of the attribute in the request. the attributes has lot of fields out of which i need to store only colname, type and value in a variable for use.

Comment: @OlayinkaO see now if it makes sense

Comment: @LakshyaSharma yeah, thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try it if attributes list:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    attribute_meta= [];

    <% for (int i=0; i<request.getAttribute("attributes").size(); i++) { %>
        attribute_meta.push({
            colName: "<%= request.getAttribute("attributes").get(i).getColName() %>",
            Type: "<%= request.getAttribute("attributes").get(i).getType() %>", 
            Value: "<%= request.getAttribute("attributes").get(i).getValue() %>"
        }); 
    <% } %>
</script>
```

or change .get(i) and .size() if not